# Comparison of various types

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion

I'm trying to make code comparing two object in various types which is stored as `System.Object`.

I tried this code:

```
object a = GetValue(..);
object b = GetValue(..);
Type t = FindCommonType(a, b);
return a < b;
```

The result of `GetValue` is an instance in one of following types: long, double, string, bool and **my own class**

Method `FindCommonType` returns an instance of `System.Type`, what it does are:

1. If the **actual type** of passed arguments are identical, then it returns `typeof(a)` which is also in respect to `typeof(b)`.
2. If the types are different, **converts** `b` to `typeof(a)` and returns `typeof(a)`.
3. The returning instance of `System.Type` could be one of following: `typeof(long)`, `typeof(int)`, `typeof(double)` and `typeof(float)`.

For example, if `a = (long)123` and `b = "123"`, then it converts `b` to `long` and returns `typeof(long)`, the code then compares them.

But the comparison `a < b` is currently unsuccessful.

How can I compare two objects in various types which are in respect to `Type t` holds?

Comment: All listed types implement IComparable. Cast your objects to IComparable interface and do comparison using IComparable.CompareTo method

Comment: thanks... Please post it as answer...